# PhoneGap App with Google Analytics, in WP7, without plugins

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, cordova, google-analytics

I developed PhoneGap app that integrates Google Analytics.
I used only "ga.js" javascript file. It is edited, replacing "file:" string with "_file:" string), and integrated in project.
I use instructions like this to register user actions:

```
window._gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Application", "start"]);
...
window._gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Pageview", pagecode]);
...
window._gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Command", command, optLabel]);
```

It works fine in Android and iOS.
But it don't works in WP7: I don't receive any error, but
Can you help me?

Comment: not sure if it's appliable, but does your WebBrowser has IsScriptEnabled=true?